# "Value at index 1 in null" in Apache Spark MulticlassMetrics.precision()

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I've trained a logistic regression model in Apache spark (pyspark), and used it to evaluate some test data... Like so...

```
# Split into train and test sets

train, test = data.randomSplit([.8, .2], seed=1337)

# Train a model

model = LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS.train(train)

# Print the coefficients

print(model.weights)

# Evaluate the test data

predictions = test.map(lambda p: (p.label, model.predict(p.features)))
print(predictions.take(100))

# Calculate and print precision and recall

metrics = MulticlassMetrics(predictions)
print("Prediction: %s" % metrics.precision(1))
```

My model coefficients print fine, and I get sane output when I print the predictions:

```
[(0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (1.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (1.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (1.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (1.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (1.0, 0), (1.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (1.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0)]
```

Unfortunately, when I call metrics.precision(1), I get a massive stack trace. The main error appears to be "Value at index 1 in null," and I'm not quite sure why that would be the case.

Incidentally, this also occurs if I try to use `BinaryClassificationMetrics` and `areaUnderPR`...

Full stack trace is below.

```
16/03/17 15:00:43 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 5.0 in stage 135.0 (TID 7806)
java.lang.NullPointerException: Value at index 1 in null
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Row$class.getAnyValAs(Row.scala:475)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Row$class.getDouble(Row.scala:243)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRow.getDouble(rows.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.MulticlassMetrics$$anonfun$$init$$1.apply(MulticlassMetrics.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.MulticlassMetrics$$anonfun$$init$$1.apply(MulticlassMetrics.scala:41)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.insertAll(ExternalSorter.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/03/17 15:00:43 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 5.0 in stage 135.0 (TID 7806, localhost): java.lang.NullPointerException: Value at index 1 in null
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Row$class.getAnyValAs(Row.scala:475)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Row$class.getDouble(Row.scala:243)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRow.getDouble(rows.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.MulticlassMetrics$$anonfun$$init$$1.apply(MulticlassMetrics.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.MulticlassMetrics$$anonfun$$init$$1.apply(MulticlassMetrics.scala:41)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.insertAll(ExternalSorter.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

16/03/17 15:00:43 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 5 in stage 135.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
16/03/17 15:00:43 WARN PythonRunner: Incomplete task interrupted: Attempting to kill Python Worker
16/03/17 15:00:43 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 6.0 in stage 135.0 (TID 7807, localhost): TaskKilled (killed intentionally)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/osboxes/PycharmProjects/Spark_Test/spark_test.py", line 96, in <module>
    print("Prediction: %s" % metrics.precision(1))
  File "/srv/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/mllib/evaluation.py", line 238, in precision
  File "/srv/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/mllib/common.py", line 146, in call
  File "/srv/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/mllib/common.py", line 123, in callJavaFunc
  File "/srv/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 813, in __call__
  File "/srv/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 45, in deco
  File "/srv/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 308, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o137.precision.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 5 in stage 135.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 5.0 in stage 135.0 (TID 7806, localhost): java.lang.NullPointerException: Value at index 1 in null
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Row$class.getAnyValAs(Row.scala:475)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Row$class.getDouble(Row.scala:243)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRow.getDouble(rows.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.MulticlassMetrics$$anonfun$$init$$1.apply(MulticlassMetrics.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.MulticlassMetrics$$anonfun$$init$$1.apply(MulticlassMetrics.scala:41)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.insertAll(ExternalSorter.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1832)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1845)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1858)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1929)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$collectAsMap$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:741)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$collectAsMap$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:740)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.collectAsMap(PairRDDFunctions.scala:740)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.MulticlassMetrics.tpByClass$lzycompute(MulticlassMetrics.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.MulticlassMetrics.tpByClass(MulticlassMetrics.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.MulticlassMetrics.precision(MulticlassMetrics.scala:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Value at index 1 in null
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Row$class.getAnyValAs(Row.scala:475)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Row$class.getDouble(Row.scala:243)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRow.getDouble(rows.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.MulticlassMetrics$$anonfun$$init$$1.apply(MulticlassMetrics.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.MulticlassMetrics$$anonfun$$init$$1.apply(MulticlassMetrics.scala:41)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.insertAll(ExternalSorter.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered the same problem. The issue is the `type` of your label - your labels are `int` whereas they should be `double`.

I reproduced/encountered the same error by doing:

```
scoreAndLabels = sc.parallelize([(1,1),(0,0),(1,0),(0,1)])
```

and fixed it by replacing:

```
scoreAndLabels = sc.parallelize([(1.,1.),(0.,0.),(1.,0.),(0.,1.)])
```

Comment: I will check into this. Thank you.

Comment: Haven't had a chance... still on the to-do list. I'll accept your answer as soon as I'm able if it works out.

Answer (score 1):

I also ran in to the same issue when I had accidentally filtered my dataset down to zero rows

Comment: Jeremy, in your case the error that should show up is "Value at index 0 is null".